# Issue with SQL Query using STR_TO_DATE

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

I am having an issue when trying to use sql query with `STR_TO_DATE` present in it. I have a table that has all the fields declared as `VARCHAR` and I can't alter this database. I still want to sort my result using the upload_date column which is present in database as a `VARCHAR`.

When I use this query :

```
select currency,STR_TO_DATE( upload_date, '%d-%m-%Y' ) AS date_for_sort 
from currency_list ORDER BY date_for_sort DESC
```

the above query runs smoothly without any error but the problem is that it's not really sorting the result as per my need, even changing it to `ASC` does not bring out any change in the result that I get, it's always the same.

Here's how table is  :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `currency_list` (
  `currency` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `code` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `rate` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `local` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `upload_date` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Sample Data from the table :

```
U.K. Pound              GBP  1.7106    0.58459      01-07-2014
U.K. Pound              GBP  1.688500  0.592242     01-06-2014
European Currency Unit  EUR  1.3867    0.721136511  01-04-2014
```

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Please edit your question and show the results and how they are not sorted as you expect them to be.

Comment: When I change the sort condition to either `ASC` or `DESC` I get the same result. My need is that it gets sorted but it's not sorting and neither it's giving any error.

Comment: Use the button `{}` to format your code properly.

Comment: Show some samples from upload_date

Comment: I have some sample data also in my question now, Mihai.

Comment: @RaghvendraMishra the sort in your sample looks as expected, What is the problem with it?

Comment: When I change it ASC, it still shows the same result.